# how to collect particular type of data with ruby scripting

Tags: ruby, file-io

I have 5 files `file1.txt file2.txt....file5.txt` then I have list of 3 words `red white blue`

I am trying to find out how many times and in what files `red white blue` occur.

Finally  the format should be:

```
red = file1.txt, file3.txt, 2
white = file2.txt, 1
blue = file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt, 3
```

This is what I have so far:

```
files.each do |i|
    curfile = File.new("#{i}","r")
    while (line = curfile.gets)
        mywords.each do |j|
           if (line ~= /\b#{j}\b/)
               ##what kind of data structure should I put the results in??
           end
        end
    end
end
```

What kind of data structure should I put the results in?

Comment: What about listing the files in an array for each color? So `red = ["file1.txt", "file3.txt"]` and so on. Then just use `red.length` to output how many times they appear.

Comment: Homework? Use a hash where each key is the color and the associated value of that key is incremented by 1 for the number of times each color is seen.

Comment: @drewk: Asking about multidimensional hashes is a legitimate question. I don't think there's a satisfactory answer for ruby yet.

Comment: @drewk your sarcastic questions aren't helpful. it was not homework but even if it was ....so what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this with following code:

```
mystring = ""
colors = %w{red white blue}
final_list = Arrays.new{colors.size}
final_list.each_with_index do |thing,index|
    final_list[index] = ""
end
files.each do |i|
    File.open("#{i}","r") { |f|
       mystring = f.read
    }
    colors.each_with_index do |thing,index|
       pattern = /#{thing}/i
       if (mystring =~ pattern)
           final_list[index] = final_list[index] + i + " "
       end
    end
end

colors.each_with_index do |thing,index|
    list = final_list[index].split (" ")
    puts "#{thing} (#{list.size})= #{list.join(',')}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
results = {}
%w(red white blue).each do |word|
  results[word] = Hash.new(0)
  %w(file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt file5.txt).each do |file|
    scanner = StringScanner.new(File.read(file))
    while (scanner.scan_until(/\b#{word}\b/)) do
      results[word][file] += 1
    end
  end
end
```

This will return a hash where the keys are the colors and the values are hashes of filenames and the number of matches in each file:

```
{'red' => {'file1.txt' => 1, 'file2.txt' => 2}, 'blue' => {'file1.txt' => 1}}
```

Comment: It may be possible to give `results` auto-vivification, such that you don't need `results[word] = Hash.new(0)`.

Comment: Yea, I believe it's possible to do `results = Hash.new(Hash.new(0))`.